# OpenCV: Wrong result in calibrateHandEye function

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision, camera-calibration, robotics

I am working in a robot application, in which I have a camera fixed to a robot gripper. In order to calculate the matrix transformation between the camera and the gripper Hcg I am using the calibrateHandEye new function provided in the OpenCV version 4.1.0

I had taken 10 pictures of the chessboard from the camera mounted in the gripper and at the same time I recorded the robot position.

The code I am working on:

```
// My_handeye.cpp : This file contains the 'main' function. Program execution begins and ends there.
//
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdio>
#include "pch.h"

#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/utility.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/calib3d.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>
#include <opencv2/videoio.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

Mat eulerAnglesToRotationMatrix(Vec3f &theta);
Vec3f rotationMatrixToEulerAngles(Mat &R);
float rad2deg(float radian);
float deg2rad(float degree);

int main()
{

    // Camera calibration information

    std::vector<double> distortionCoefficients(5);  // camera distortion
    distortionCoefficients[0] = 2.4472856611074989e-01;
    distortionCoefficients[1] = -8.1042032574246325e-01;
    distortionCoefficients[2] = 0;
    distortionCoefficients[3] = 0;
    distortionCoefficients[4] = 7.8769462320821060e-01;

    double f_x = 1.3624172121852105e+03; // Focal length in x axis
    double f_y = 1.3624172121852105e+03; // Focal length in y axis (usually the same?)
    double c_x = 960; // Camera primary point x
    double c_y = 540; // Camera primary point y

    cv::Mat cameraMatrix(3, 3, CV_32FC1);
    cameraMatrix.at<float>(0, 0) = f_x;
    cameraMatrix.at<float>(0, 1) = 0.0;
    cameraMatrix.at<float>(0, 2) = c_x;
    cameraMatrix.at<float>(1, 0) = 0.0;
    cameraMatrix.at<float>(1, 1) = f_y;
    cameraMatrix.at<float>(1, 2) = c_y;
    cameraMatrix.at<float>(2, 0) = 0.0;
    cameraMatrix.at<float>(2, 1) = 0.0;
    cameraMatrix.at<float>(2, 2) = 1.0;

    Mat rvec(3, 1, CV_32F), tvec(3, 1, CV_32F);
    //

    std::vector<Mat> R_gripper2base;
    std::vector<Mat> t_gripper2base;
    std::vector<Mat> R_target2cam;
    std::vector<Mat> t_target2cam;
    Mat R_cam2gripper = (Mat_<float>(3, 3));
    Mat t_cam2gripper = (Mat_<float>(3, 1));

    vector<String> fn;
    glob("images/*.bmp", fn, false);

    vector<Mat> images;
    size_t num_images = fn.size(); //number of bmp files in images folder
    Size patternsize(6, 8); //number of centers
    vector<Point2f> centers; //this will be filled by the detected centers
    float cell_size = 30;
    vector<Point3f> obj_points;

    R_gripper2base.reserve(num_images);
    t_gripper2base.reserve(num_images);
    R_target2cam.reserve(num_images);
    t_target2cam.reserve(num_images);

    for (int i = 0; i < patternsize.height; ++i)
        for (int j = 0; j < patternsize.width; ++j)
            obj_points.push_back(Point3f(float(j*cell_size),
                float(i*cell_size), 0.f));

    for (size_t i = 0; i < num_images; i++)
        images.push_back(imread(fn[i]));

    Mat frame;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < num_images; i++)
    {
        frame = imread(fn[i]); //source image
        bool patternfound = findChessboardCorners(frame, patternsize, centers);
        if (patternfound)
        {
            drawChessboardCorners(frame, patternsize, Mat(centers), patternfound);
            //imshow("window", frame);
            //int key = cv::waitKey(0) & 0xff;
            solvePnP(Mat(obj_points), Mat(centers), cameraMatrix, distortionCoefficients, rvec, tvec);

            Mat R;
            Rodrigues(rvec, R); // R is 3x3
            R_target2cam.push_back(R);
            t_target2cam.push_back(tvec);
            Mat T = Mat::eye(4, 4, R.type()); // T is 4x4
            T(Range(0, 3), Range(0, 3)) = R * 1; // copies R into T
            T(Range(0, 3), Range(3, 4)) = tvec * 1; // copies tvec into T

            cout << "T = " << endl << " " << T << endl << endl;

        }
        cout << patternfound << endl;
    }

    Vec3f theta_01{ deg2rad(-153.61), deg2rad(8.3),   deg2rad(-91.91) };
    Vec3f theta_02{ deg2rad(-166.71), deg2rad(3.04),  deg2rad(-93.31) };
    Vec3f theta_03{ deg2rad(-170.04), deg2rad(24.92), deg2rad(-88.29) };
    Vec3f theta_04{ deg2rad(-165.71), deg2rad(24.68), deg2rad(-84.85) };
    Vec3f theta_05{ deg2rad(-160.18), deg2rad(-15.94),deg2rad(-56.24) };
    Vec3f theta_06{ deg2rad(175.68),  deg2rad(10.95), deg2rad(180) };
    Vec3f theta_07{ deg2rad(175.73),  deg2rad(45.78), deg2rad(-179.92) };
    Vec3f theta_08{ deg2rad(-165.34), deg2rad(47.37), deg2rad(-166.25) };
    Vec3f theta_09{ deg2rad(-165.62), deg2rad(17.95), deg2rad(-166.17) };
    Vec3f theta_10{ deg2rad(-151.99), deg2rad(-14.59),deg2rad(-94.19) };

    Mat robot_rot_01 = eulerAnglesToRotationMatrix(theta_01);
    Mat robot_rot_02 = eulerAnglesToRotationMatrix(theta_02);
    Mat robot_rot_03 = eulerAnglesToRotationMatrix(theta_03);
    Mat robot_rot_04 = eulerAnglesToRotationMatrix(theta_04);
    Mat robot_rot_05 = eulerAnglesToRotationMatrix(theta_05);
    Mat robot_rot_06 = eulerAnglesToRotationMatrix(theta_06);
    Mat robot_rot_07 = eulerAnglesToRotationMatrix(theta_07);
    Mat robot_rot_08 = eulerAnglesToRotationMatrix(theta_08);
    Mat robot_rot_09 = eulerAnglesToRotationMatrix(theta_09);
    Mat robot_rot_10 = eulerAnglesToRotationMatrix(theta_10);

    const Mat robot_tr_01 = (Mat_<float>(3, 1) << 781.2, 338.59, 903.48);
    const Mat robot_tr_02 = (Mat_<float>(3, 1) << 867.65, 382.52, 884.42);
    const Mat robot_tr_03 = (Mat_<float>(3, 1) << 856.91, 172.99, 964.61);
    const Mat robot_tr_04 = (Mat_<float>(3, 1) << 748.81, 146.75, 1043.29);
    const Mat robot_tr_05 = (Mat_<float>(3, 1) << 627.66, 554.08, 920.85);
    const Mat robot_tr_06 = (Mat_<float>(3, 1) << 715.06, 195.96, 889.38);
    const Mat robot_tr_07 = (Mat_<float>(3, 1) << 790.9, 196.29, 1117.38);
    const Mat robot_tr_08 = (Mat_<float>(3, 1) << 743.5, 283.93, 1131.92);
    const Mat robot_tr_09 = (Mat_<float>(3, 1) << 748.9, 288.19, 910.58);
    const Mat robot_tr_10 = (Mat_<float>(3, 1) << 813.18, 400.44, 917.16);

    R_gripper2base.push_back(robot_rot_01);
    R_gripper2base.push_back(robot_rot_02);
    R_gripper2base.push_back(robot_rot_03);
    R_gripper2base.push_back(robot_rot_04);
    R_gripper2base.push_back(robot_rot_05);
    R_gripper2base.push_back(robot_rot_06);
    R_gripper2base.push_back(robot_rot_07);
    R_gripper2base.push_back(robot_rot_08);
    R_gripper2base.push_back(robot_rot_09);
    R_gripper2base.push_back(robot_rot_10);

    t_gripper2base.push_back(robot_tr_01);
    t_gripper2base.push_back(robot_tr_02);
    t_gripper2base.push_back(robot_tr_03);
    t_gripper2base.push_back(robot_tr_04);
    t_gripper2base.push_back(robot_tr_05);
    t_gripper2base.push_back(robot_tr_06);
    t_gripper2base.push_back(robot_tr_07);
    t_gripper2base.push_back(robot_tr_08);
    t_gripper2base.push_back(robot_tr_09);
    t_gripper2base.push_back(robot_tr_10);

    calibrateHandEye(R_gripper2base, t_gripper2base, R_target2cam, t_target2cam, R_cam2gripper, t_cam2gripper, CALIB_HAND_EYE_TSAI);

    Vec3f R_cam2gripper_r = rotationMatrixToEulerAngles(R_cam2gripper);

    cout << "R_cam2gripper = " << endl << " " << R_cam2gripper << endl << endl;
    cout << "R_cam2gripper_r = " << endl << " " << R_cam2gripper_r << endl << endl;
    cout << "t_cam2gripper = " << endl << " " << t_cam2gripper << endl << endl;
}

Mat eulerAnglesToRotationMatrix(Vec3f &theta)
{
    // Calculate rotation about x axis
    Mat R_x = (Mat_<double>(3, 3) <<
        1, 0, 0,
        0, cos(theta[0]), -sin(theta[0]),
        0, sin(theta[0]), cos(theta[0])
        );

    // Calculate rotation about y axis
    Mat R_y = (Mat_<double>(3, 3) <<
        cos(theta[1]), 0, sin(theta[1]),
        0, 1, 0,
        -sin(theta[1]), 0, cos(theta[1])
        );

    // Calculate rotation about z axis
    Mat R_z = (Mat_<double>(3, 3) <<
        cos(theta[2]), -sin(theta[2]), 0,
        sin(theta[2]), cos(theta[2]), 0,
        0, 0, 1);


    // Combined rotation matrix
    Mat R = R_z * R_y * R_x;

    return R;

}

float rad2deg(float radian) {
    double pi = 3.14159;
    return(radian * (180 / pi));
}

float deg2rad(float degree) {
    double pi = 3.14159;
    return(degree * (pi / 180));
}

// Checks if a matrix is a valid rotation matrix.
bool isRotationMatrix(Mat &R)
{
    Mat Rt;
    transpose(R, Rt);
    Mat shouldBeIdentity = Rt * R;
    Mat I = Mat::eye(3, 3, shouldBeIdentity.type());

    return  norm(I, shouldBeIdentity) < 1e-6;

}

// Calculates rotation matrix to euler angles
// The result is the same as MATLAB except the order
// of the euler angles ( x and z are swapped ).
Vec3f rotationMatrixToEulerAngles(Mat &R)
{

    assert(isRotationMatrix(R));

    float sy = sqrt(R.at<double>(0, 0) * R.at<double>(0, 0) + R.at<double>(1, 0) * R.at<double>(1, 0));

    bool singular = sy < 1e-6; // If

    float x, y, z;
    if (!singular)
    {
        x = atan2(R.at<double>(2, 1), R.at<double>(2, 2));
        y = atan2(-R.at<double>(2, 0), sy);
        z = atan2(R.at<double>(1, 0), R.at<double>(0, 0));
    }
    else
    {
        x = atan2(-R.at<double>(1, 2), R.at<double>(1, 1));
        y = atan2(-R.at<double>(2, 0), sy);
        z = 0;
    }
    return Vec3f(x, y, z);

}
```

The result the function is giving me is the next one:

```
R_cam2gripper =
 [0.3099803593003124, -0.8923086952824562, -0.3281727733547833;
 0.7129271761196039, 0.4465219155360299, -0.5406967916458927;
 0.6290047840821058, -0.0663579028402444, 0.7745641421680119]

R_cam2gripper_r =
 [-0.0854626, -0.680272, 1.16065]

t_cam2gripper =
 [-35.02063730299775;
 -74.80633768251272;
 -307.6725851251873]
```

I am getting  'good' results provided by other software. With them, the robot got to the exact points I am pointing in the camera (I have a 3D camera, from which I am getting the x, y, z from the camera world) so they are certainly correct, but I am having troubles to repeat the same result with the OpenCV function.

Sorry for the long introduction to my problem. Any understanding of why the solutions are not what is supposed to be? My guess is, that I have a problem understanding the angles or converting them but I couldn't find any way to solve this. Any hint will be well welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually managed to solve this problem. The general idea was correct, but:

1. I was not understanding correctly the vector rotation notation the robot was giving. It was necessary to multiply the actual values by a factor.
2. I created a new program that extracts directly from the robot and the pictures the matrixes that the algorithm requires and writes these values to a YML file.
3. The CALIB_HAND_EYE_TSAI method wasn't giving me correct values. But with the four others, the values seem to converge to the actual values

Anyway, thank you for your help. I am stuck to get more precision in the algorithm, but that's for another question.